# Tree sizes given by CP table in rpart

Tags: r, tree, decision-tree, cross-validation, rpart

In the R package rpart, what determines the size of trees presented within the CP table for a decision tree? In the below example, the CP table defaults to presenting only trees with 1, 2, and 5 nodes (as nsplit = 0, 1 and 4 respectively).

```
library(rpart)   
fit <- rpart(Kyphosis ~ Age + Number + Start, method="class", data=kyphosis)
> printcp(fit) 

Classification tree:
rpart(formula = Kyphosis ~ Age + Number + Start, data = kyphosis, 
method = "class")

Variables actually used in tree construction:
[1] Age   Start

Root node error: 17/81 = 0.20988

n= 81 

        CP nsplit rel error  xerror    xstd
1 0.176471      0   1.00000 1.00000 0.21559
2 0.019608      1   0.82353 0.94118 0.21078
3 0.010000      4   0.76471 0.94118 0.21078
```

Is there an inherent rule `rpart()` used to determine what size of trees to present? And is it possible to force `printcp()` to return cross-validation statistics for all possible sizes of tree, i.e. for the above example, also include rows for trees with 3 and 4 nodes (nsplit = 2, 3)?

Answer (score 3):

The `rpart()` function is controlled using the `rpart.control()` function. It has parameters such as `minsplit` which tells the function to only split when there are more observations then the value specified and `cp` which tells the function to only split if the overall lack of fit is decreased by a factor of `cp`.
If you look at `summary(fit)` on your above example it shows the statistics for all values of `nsplit`. To get these values to print when using `printcp(fit)` you need to choose appropriate values of `cp` and `minsplit` when calling the original `rpart` function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I was under the impression that `minsplit` and `cp` are parameters used in growing the tree before cross-validation is attempted - rather than pruning it afterwards, which is what my question and the CP table refer to. If I've misunderstood would you be able to advise why the output above only presents nsplit = 0, 1, 4 and what appropriate values of `minsplit` and `cp` might be to present nsplit = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4?

Incidentally, `summary(fit)` did not give me cross-validation statistics for all values of nsplit - the CP table it showed is the same as the question.

Comment: It doesn't show those splits (nsplit = 2, 3) because they don't improve the misclassification rate.

Answer (score 1):

The cran-r documentation on rpart mentions adding option cp=0 to the rpart function. http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rpart/vignettes/longintro.pdf
It also mentions other options which can be given in the rpart function for eg to control the number of splits.

```
    dfit <- rpart(y ~ x, method='class',
            control = rpart.control(xval = 10, minbucket = 2, **cp = 0**))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but as above, I believe `minbucket` and `cp` only influence the growing of the tree, not the cross-validation pruning that comes afterwards. In this case, adding `control = rpart.control(cp = 0)` did not change the CP table presented in the question.

Comment: I don't know how you can force more options to display all splits. Unless there is an additional gain with the split, I dont think rpart will include it in the output. Also the kyphosis is a small dataset with only 81 obs. If you see the CP plot with the options below , there isn't much chance in the X Relative Error between 1 and 3 and hence nsplit=2 is not considered altogether.                                                                           fit2 <- rpart(Kyphosis ~ Age + Number + Start,data=kyphosis,
              method="class",control=rpart.control(minsplit=8))  
rsq.rpart(fit2)

Comment: The `cp` is a hyperparameter of cost complexity, so it surely controls de prunning process. The algoritm when using K-fold CV will try to minimize this:
$\sum_{m = 1}^{|T|} \ \sum_{x_i \in R_m} (y_i - \hat{y}_{R_m}) ^ 2 + \alpha |T|$, where $|T|$ is the number of terminal nodes (leaves), $R_m$ is the rectangle (a subset of the feature space) and $\hat{y}_{R_m}$ is the mean of the observations that fall down in the $R_m$ region. $\alpha$ here is the `cp`. when you set `cp = 0`, you are only minimizing the SSE, not considering the prunning.      
Source: Introduction to Statistical Learning